# Difference between "Make a choice" and "Make a desicion"/"Take a decision"

Tags: translation, spanish

In spanish we normally say "Tomar una decisión". But, which one will be the correct translation?

- Make a choice
- Make a decision
- Take a decision

**Decision**:  the act of or need for making up one’s mind.

**Choice**:  the right, power, or opportunity to choose.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6431/what-is-the-difference-between-make-decision-and-take-decision

Comment: English Language Learners is where you should be.

Answer (score 2):

> Make a decision

This is a general act and implies a multitude of options, abstract options or unspecific other options. For example, "I finally **made a decision** about what to do with my finances."

> Make a choice

In this situation, you are describing a specific action from a limited or specific number of options. For example, in the movie the Matrix, Keanu Reeves is offered a choice between the blue pill and the red pill.

**Decide** is NEVER used in a transitive situation, ie with a direct object. Whereas, **choose** can be used as both a transitive and intransitive verb.

You can say.

> I **choose** the red pill.

You can also say

> I **choose to take** the red pill.

If you wanted to use decide in this sentence, it MUST be used with an infinitive following it.

> I **decide TO TAKE** the red pill.
>   You cannot say *I decide the red pill*

I found a good source that describes choose as **catenative** verb.

> Usage notes:
>
> - This is a catenative verb that takes the to infinitive.

[This comes from Wikidiff.com](https://wikidiff.com/decide/chose)

And finally, in my dialect of English (American), I would never say:

> Take a decision.

Comment: *take a decision* seems to be what committees do, in some professional argot.

Answer (score 1):

Make a decision is the English equivalent of tomar una decisión.

It's not uncommon for different languages to use different verbs for actions like these.

Caution:  this is for American English.  British English might be different.

Answer (score -1):

A committee could just as well make a decision.  That sounds better to me